# kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection timed out when trying to ssh to a laptop on LAN

Tags: windows, ssh

So I've got a laptop running Pop! OS (20.04 LTS), I've just installed openssh-server via `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` and I'm attempting to SSH into it from my Windows 10 desktop PC but I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\enricojr\.ssh> ssh -vvv 192.168.254.203
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\enricojr/.ssh/config
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.254.203 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.254.203 [192.168.254.203] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\enricojr/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/enricojr/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/enricojr/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\enricojr/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/enricojr/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/enricojr/.ssh/id_dsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\enricojr/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/enricojr/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/enricojr/.ssh/id_dsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\enricojr/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/enricojr/.ssh/id_ecdsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/enricojr/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\enricojr/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/enricojr/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/enricojr/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\enricojr/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/enricojr/.ssh/id_ed25519 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/enricojr/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\enricojr/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/enricojr/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/enricojr/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\enricojr/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/enricojr/.ssh/id_xmss error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/enricojr/.ssh/id_xmss.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\enricojr/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/enricojr/.ssh/id_xmss-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/enricojr/.ssh/id_xmss-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\enricojr/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug3: recv - from CB(2) ERROR:138, io:000001B6A4A39080
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection timed out
```

Ping is fine, tracert is fine too (unless otherwise specified all commands are being run from Windows Powershell)

```
PS C:\Users\enricojr\.ssh> tracert 192.168.254.203

Tracing route to 192.168.254.203 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     2 ms     1 ms     2 ms  192.168.254.203

Trace complete.

PS C:\Users\enricojr\.ssh> ping 192.168.254.203

Pinging 192.168.254.203 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.254.203: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.254.203: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.254.203: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.254.203: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.254.203:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 2ms, Average = 2ms
```

Running `ssh localhost` directly on remote (I have the laptop in front of me) prompts me for password and then "connects" just fine.

I was able to `scp` the public key I wanted to use from my desktop to remote just fine as well.

Additionally, I am able to SSH from desktop to a completely different remote, my Macbook Pro.

I'm almost certain the issue is with the openssh-server installation on pop os but it's pretty much stock, I haven't run any additional commands beyond `sudo systemctl stop/restart/status` since installing it, and I was under the impression that this would work out of the box.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

edit1:
results of ssh-keyscan on desktop -> remote

```
PS C:\Users\enricojr\.ssh> ssh-keyscan 192.168.254.203
read (192.168.254.203): Connection timed out
read (192.168.254.203): Connection timed out
read (192.168.254.203): Connection timed out
```

Comment: What does `ssh-keyscan 192.168.254.203` yield? You can edit your question and post the extra information.

Comment: @Halfgaar all done, post has been updated. Basically "connection timed out"

Comment: Does the SSH server log say something useful? Typically, that's `/var/log/auth.log`, but I don't know Pop! OS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is just a coincidence or not -

When I first set this machine up I set up a static IP address outside my router's DHCP range, but neglected to set the netmask properly.

Changing it from 0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.0 and restarting seems to have fixed the problem, but I don't see what the netmask has to do with any of this so it could all just be coincidence.

Comment: The netmask determines whether local net or your gateway gets the replies. It makes sense that you'd get weird connection errors then.

Comment: That does it then. I was watching tcpdump output and seeing responses go out normally while I was debugging this so yeah it makes sense now.